# How can I make power method?

Tags: javascript

I want make the power method 
I made this :

```js
var x = 2, n = 3, i;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  x = x * x;
}
console.log(x);
```

This gives `16` as result but expected is `x^n = 8`.

Comment: What result does it give?

Comment: The `i` in for loop should start from `2`

Comment: I hope you know there is `Math.pow()`?

Comment: You're doing `(2 * 2) * (2 * 2)`, not `2 * 2 * 2`. Going through this with pen and paper would have revealed that quickly.

Answer (score 3):

This function doesn't compute the power because it squares the intermediate results. You should use a separate variable like this:

```
var x= 2 ,n= 3, i;
var y = x;
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    x *= y;
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: This is incomplete at best. How about `pow(x, -3)`? `pow(x, 0.5)`?

Comment: @georg: The OP asks for a solution of his code and not for a general solution to compute the power of two floats. Extending the code for negative integer exponents is easy (computing the power of `-n` and returning the reciprocal). For fractional values there is no easy solution, but this wasn't the question here. For that case you should use `math.pow()` as already suggested.

Comment: Even for natural powers (although nobody mentions them), this is still a lazy, incomplete answer. Please consider improving it.

Comment: @georg: Yes, it is not the best solution. It's a correction of a given code. That's all. A binary algorithm should be much faster especially for large values of `n`. But this wasn't the question, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try recursion:

```
const power = ( base, exponent ) => {
    if( exponent === 0 ) return 1; 
    else return base * power( base, exponent - 1 );
};
```

Or try the normal for loop:

```
const power = ( base, exponent ) => {
    let result = 1;
    for( let i = 0; i < exponent; i++ )
        result *= base;
    return result;
};
```

The reason yours isn't working is because it tries to compute `x = x^2` for `n` steps. Hence, the calculation is `2^2 = 4^2 = 16`. The above code, instead, has a `result` variable which multiplies the `base` an `exponent` number of times.

Comment: *"Or try the normal for loop"* - The OP's code already has a normal for loop. Care to explain what's wrong with theirs?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the built-in method `Math.pow(number, power)`.

```js
console.log(Math.pow(2, 10));
```

Comment: He's trying to use something on his own (possibly for understanding).

Comment: I think your down vote is immature :) You may have just commented.

Comment: It doesn't the question *at hand*.